# node.js calling firebase `iinitializeApp(` function results in exit code 6

Tags: php, node.js, apache, firebase

I'm using PHP to call (using `shell_exec`, `passthru` etc, I've tried many of them) a local script with shebang pointing to `/usr/bin/node`.

When calling from commandline with `php file_calling_node_script.php` or `php5` everything works fine; but when calling from browser, the `shell_exec` part doesn't return anything any more.

I chose other simpler node scripts and they were all fine, and through multiple testings I have found out that at least the line calling `initializeApp`from `"firebase-admin": "^4.0.4"` has been causing this, and `passthru` tells me the exit code would be 6.
Using `2>&1` still results in empty output and the exit code would become 134 instead of 6.

Could someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the php logs for when you're testing with the browser?

Comment: @brandonscript I'm using a shared hosting, and though I do receive information from the logs, it has no records regarding the pertinent  operations and I can't do much to configure the logs.

Comment: What about enabling php errors for the browser?

Comment: @brandonscript I use `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and nothing more was there to show.

Comment: Hm... no idea then. If PHP isn't throwing any errors, then I have no idea why.

Comment: @brandonscript Thanks anyways!